# How to solve this problem Attempt to read property "XXX" on null

Tags: laravel

I get these errors after migration:

```
1- ErrorException
Attempt to read property "sliders" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ `_slider.blade.php`)

2- ErrorException
Attempt to read property "tracking" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ `_tracking.blade.php`)

3- ErrorException
Attempt to read property "about_us" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ `_about.blade.php`)

4- ErrorException
Attempt to read property "branches" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ `_our_branches.blade.php`)

5- ErrorException
Attempt to read property "services" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ `_services.blade.php`)

6- ErrorException
Attempt to read property "partners" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ `_partners.blade.php`)

7- ErrorException
Attempt to read property "sliders" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ `_header.blade.php`)

8- ErrorException
Attempt to read property "mini_logo_ar" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ `_footer.blade.php`)

9- Error Call to a member
Call to a member function getTranslation() on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\arsl\resources\views\layouts\website\ `app.blade.php`)
```

The error in the variable `$company` is `null`.

##### `Company.php` Model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models\Admin;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations;

class Company extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use HasTranslations;

    public $translatable = ['name', 'description', 'location'];

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'phone', 'email', 'tax_number', 'commercial_register', 'created_by', 'tracking', 'status', 'location', 'description', 'website_logo_ar', 'website_logo_en', 'dashboard_logo_ar', 'dashboard_logo_en', 'mini_logo_ar', 'mini_logo_en', 'favicon', 'branches', 'services', 'partners', 'sliders', 'about_us'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'created_by');
    }
}
```

##### `CompanyController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Admin\Company;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class CompanyController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $company = Company::get()->first();
        return view('admin.company.index' , compact('company'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $company = Company::findOrFail($id);

        $files = [
            [
                'column' => 'website_logo_ar',
                'oldValue' => $company->website_logo_ar
            ],
            [
                'column' => 'website_logo_en',
                'oldValue' => $company->website_logo_en
            ],
            [
                'column' => 'dashboard_logo_ar',
                'oldValue' => $company->dashboard_logo_ar
            ],
            [
                'column' => 'dashboard_logo_en',
                'oldValue' => $company->dashboard_logo_en
            ],
            [
                'column' => 'mini_logo_ar',
                'oldValue' => $company->mini_logo_ar
            ],
            [
                'column' => 'mini_logo_en',
                'oldValue' => $company->mini_logo_en
            ],
            [
                'column' => 'favicon',
                'oldValue' => $company->favicon
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($files as $index => $row){

            $column = $row['column'];
            $fileToStore = '$fileNameToStore_' . $index;
            $oldFile = '$old_file_' . $row['column'];

            if($request->hasFile($row['column'])) {
                // Get Filename With The Extension
                $filenameWithExt = $request->file($column)->getClientOriginalName();
                // Get Just Filename
                $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt , PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                // Get Just Extension
                $extension = $request->file($column)->getClientOriginalExtension();
                // File To Store
                $fileToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
                // Upload Image
                $path = $request->file($column)->storeAs('public/images/company/' , $fileToStore);
            }

            if($request->hasFile($column)){
                $company[$column] = $fileToStore;
                if($oldFile != ''){
                    Storage::delete('public/images/company/' . $row['oldValue']);
                }
            }

        }

        $company->name = ['ar' => $request->name_ar,'en' => $request->name_en];
        $company->location = ['ar' => $request->location_ar,'en' => $request->location_en];
        $company->description = ['ar' => $request->description_ar,'en' => $request->description_en];
        $company->phone = $request->phone;
        $company->email = $request->email;
        $company->sliders = $request->sliders ? $request->sliders : 'off';
        $company->about_us = $request->about_us ? $request->about_us : 'off';
        $company->services = $request->services ? $request->services : 'off';
        $company->branches = $request->branches ? $request->branches : 'off';
        $company->partners = $request->partners ? $request->partners : 'off';
        $company->tax_number = $request->tax_number;
        $company->commercial_register = $request->commercial_register;
        $company->tracking = $request->tracking ? $request->tracking : 'off';

        $company->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success' , __('main.data has been updated'));
    }
}
```

I changed all `$company` variables from `$company->` to `$company && $company->` .

I don't know if it's correct and solve the problem or not.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: clearly mention the question instead of showing all the codes

Comment: Your change from `$company->` to `$company && $company->` is a start, but it won't fully solve the issue as it still errors if `$company` is null. Using the optional operator (`??`) is a more effective solution.

Comment: how can I use (??) optional operator

Comment: `$company->tracking = $request->tracking ?? 'off'; `  
About your question, please detail the line of your error. Maybe your error has a simple solution like `if ($company != null)`

Comment: Also, you can cast directly the param, like this: `public function update(Request $request, Company $company) {` This will throw a ModelNotFoundException  (or something like that) if your company doesn't exists. This is translated as 404 response in your browser or api client.

Comment: My problem is solved but I have another problem.
in the register page I fill all the data, but when I press create account it does not redirecting me to the dashboard or admin page. and if I go to login page and try to login with the data I create on register page it does not redirecting me to the dashboard or admin page.
what is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.